# Password reset link taking me to homepage

Tags: ee2, members

When I request the password reset, it generates a URL:

http://mywebsite.com?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&resetcode=rt4RTVHl

However, this takes me to the homepage of the site, not the password reset page.

Any ideas why this might be. Using the native members module 2.1

EE version 2.9.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you didn't set your CP URL correctly.

You can set it with a [config override (v3 docs).](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#overrides-cp-url) For example:

```
$config['cp_url'] = 'http://example.com/admin.php';
```

[EE v2 docs reference here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#overrides-cp-url)

Answer (score 1):

When running EE 2.9.2, a default install password reset URL should have this structure:

https://mywebsite.com/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&resetcode=%generated_reset_code%

I would suspect what Alex mentioned; you probably don't have your CP URL set correctly, or you are overridding it somewhere.

Look at the link you have; it has a query string attached to the homepage and not to any apparent administrative scripts or paths. I believe only ACTion URL query strings have any value at your homepage in EE, besides any that you generate and use yourself in your homepage template (or if an EE addon does).